# Como importar um cursor .cur em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu estou com um problema ao carregar um arquivo de cursor no Windows Forms.

Tipo eu coloco os arquivos na pasta mas o programa avista que o arquivo de cursos não é válido ou está corrompido. Mas eu preciso muito desses cursores para o desenvolvimento de um aplicartivo.

Eu tentei utilizar este código para resolver o meu problema:

```
void FormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.Cursor = new Cursor("app\\point.cur");
}
```

mas o código citado acima não funcionou.

Tentei este também mas não funcionou tambem:

```
void FormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Cursor.Current = new Cursor("app\\point.cur");
}
```

O **VS2010** diz a seguinte mensagem:

**Formato de imagem inválido. Talvez o arquivo de imagem esteja corrompido.

Nome do parâmetro: stream**

Comment: Só citando o que está sendo argumentado é a exception:

**ArgumentException**

Comment: Mas tem alguma dúvida? A mensagem de erro é bem clara qual o seu problema. O problema não está no código. Qualquer das duas formas podem estar corretas ou erradas, só com este trecho não dá para saber qual é a certa mas não importa porque o erro ocorre antes de atribuir para algum membro.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione o .cur no resources da sua aplicação... ai ele vai estar junto ao seu projeto e não sera um arquivo externo ao seu projeto.

Tanto pode ser assim:

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(new System.IO.MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.point));
```

Quanto assim:

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("NomeAplicacao.point.cur"));
```

Para esse ultimo caso... voce pode conseguir o nome correto utilizando o seguinte comando(puxa todos os resourcesname da pasta de resources):

```
String[] resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```